# Draw multiple donut charts with Plotly

Tags: plotly, plotly-python, donut-chart

Does anyone know if there is a way to draw multiple dynamic donut charts in one chart, and show a scroll-down arrow if the donuts exceeded 6 multi?

Data example:

```
value = c(3,5,200.....), 
 Target = c(10,20,250.....), 
 KPI = c("Sec1","Sec2","Sec3","Sec4",....)
```

I am trying to present it same to the following picture:
[image]

Thanks in advance